# How to add ExpandableListView inside a ListView?

Tags: java, android

I have added a expandableListView inside a list view but expandableListView have not expand and just only see first item of expand listview. Help me

Comment: Why you need such thing, you may customize your ListView to achieve the same

Comment: I need to show listview: shop name, image and list expandable listview about user of shop.

Answer (score 1):

use this site "https://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial"
for generating ExpandableListView.

Comment: That is just ExpandableListView. I want show ExpandableListview inside a parent List View.

Comment: you can add child to it